why am I getting this warning?
'realloc' may return null pointer: assigning a null pointer to 'parameter-name', which is passed as an argument to 'realloc', will cause the original memory block to be leaked.
I am getting the above warning on the 2 lines where I use realloc, does anybody know what am I doing wrong here?
here is the code:
if (sequenceLength == size)
{
   size *= 2;
   sequence=realloc(sequence, size);        
   if (sequence == NULL)
   {
      printf("reallocation was unsuccessful.");
      free(sequence);
      free(playerInput);
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }

   playerInput=realloc(playerInput, size);
   if (playerInput == NULL)
   {
        printf("reallocation was unsuccessful.");
        free(sequence);
        free(playerInput);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}

I tried searching for it online but couldnt find anything.

What is inclear with the warning? Use a temporary pointer to accept the value returned by realloc.

Because by reassigning sequence to a new value, you've lost the old pointer. The original memory can't be freed when realloc() returns NULL. Use a temporary variable.

Searching that warning gives very clear answers. Have you read the documentation for the command to see what it may return?

As the warning says, if you assign the return value of realloc directly back to the pointer you're reallocating and the call fails, you now have a memory leak since the pointer to the original memory block is lost.  If realloc fails, the original block of memory is still valid.
You need to assign the result to a temporary variable, and then only assign it back if it is successful.
   void *tmp=realloc(sequence, size);        
   if (tmp == NULL)
   {
      printf("reallocation was unsuccessful.");
      free(sequence);
      free(playerInput);
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
   sequence = tmp;


Thnx for the comment. Ok I got that I need a temp pointer.
But I guess I still don’t completely understand how realloc works.
When I use it does the original memory block get freed? If so why is it lost when I do it my way?

@AlonKalif realloc will sometimes reuse the same block of memory and sometimes give you a different block.  Either way, if the call fails and returns NULL and you assign that right back to sequence, you no longer have a pointer to what sequence previously pointed to.  A failed call to realloc leaves the original allocated memory unchanged.
